# Integration Testing .net core 2.1 application without test server

Tags: c#, .net, integration-testing, asp.net-core-2.1

I want to test business logic class method which fetches configurations from appsettings.json file using MSTEST.

I created test project and copied appsettings.json and startup.cs files from main project to test project.

```
    [TestClass]
public class TestClass
{
    private BusinessLogicClass businessLogicClass;


    [TestInitialize]
    public void TestInitialize()
    {
        var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
         .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
         .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: false).Build();
         var host = WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder()
                .UseStartup<Startup>()  
                .Build();
            host.Run();
            businessLogicClass = new BusinessLogicClass();

    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod()
    {

        // Calling BusinessLogicClass Method
            businessLogicClass.MethodToTest();

    }
```

When I debug the test test project gets stuck at host.run and never executes test method. Please help me.

Comment: Can you add the code that show how you are fetching the configuration inside your `MethodToTest()`.

Comment: Through Startup.Configuration                                                                          var DBName =  Startup.Configuration["Databases:DatabaseName"];

Comment: Clearly you should not attempt to call `Run` which is a blocking method.

Comment: @LexLi  How will test project initialize settings without host.Run

Comment: The `Configuration` property of `Startup` is not static, so I am confused how you are accessing it. Can you post your business logic class?

Comment: This is my startup class

        public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                .AddEnvironmentVariables();
            Configuration = builder.Build();
   
   }
   
   public static IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; private set; }
   
and in my business class i am simply using
DBName = Startup.Configuration["Databases:DatabaseName"];

Comment: When posting additional information, can you edit your original post by clicking the edit link under your question. It is easier to read.

Comment: Is it really that hard to simply read the source code? https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/blob/f9d145887773e0c650e66165e0c61886153bcc0b/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting/WebHostExtensions.cs#L104 `Run` is not mandate if you read carefully. I think calling `IWebHost.Start` should be enough.

Comment: I'm not sure you understand what integration testing is. If you're trying to do an integration test involving making a request you *need* the test server. What you're essentially trying to do is roll your own test server (and not well), which makes no sense, when the functionality you need already exists.

Comment: If you're not going to actually make a request, then what you have is merely a *unit test*. In which case, you're going to need to mock out all the dependencies. You cannot rely on building a web host for that.